# Add column names to list given criteria

Tags: python, tuples, unsupportedoperation

I'm trying to add column names (in form of tuples) from a dataframe to a list given a certain criteria. The criteria is simply if the data under each column is 1 (by itself, not as part of a string or a float). This is what I usually use, and it works, but only for smaller data sets (when scaled up, it renders a TypeError -- unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'):

```
peaks_to_delete = []
for col in df3.columns:   #dataframe is df3
    if sum(df3[col]) == 1:
        peaks_to_delete.append(col)
```

Column names look like `(125.98617542491242, 14.707909313725589)` `(332.3316802978516, 14.558341666666749)` and so on...

I understand the error but don't get why the code works on smaller datasets and not larger ones.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the dimensions of the 'small' and 'large' datasets? And do they have the same type and number of values?

Comment: The "small" dataset contains 4 rows x 1506 columns and the "larger" contains 8 rows x 1752. Which, now that I write them down, doesn't seem like a huge difference. Same type of values. Same number of values under each column, either a 1 or a 0.

Comment: Without knowing more about the data or manipulations, it definitely looks like there's something in those last 246 columns that is throwing the error, not the append loop. Can you provide the full traceback of the error? And what if you run it on a few cols at a time until one errors?

Comment: The error goes back to the this line of code `if sum(df3[col]) == 1` . Its weird cuz the data set is essentially the same w/the exception of a couple hundred more data points. Even when I break down the set to run on the same amount of columns it still errors.

Comment: This most likely has _nothing_ to do with the number of columns you run it against. It sounds like you have some value in one of the last columns that contains one or more tuples where the rest are numbers. You can run a for loop over `for col in df.columns:` and give it `try: x=sum(df[col])` and `except: print(col)` to see which column(s) won't sum

Comment: So I used the code: `for col in df_850.columns:` and used `try: print(sum(df_850[col]))` as well as `except: print(col)` and found that two columns didn't sum and instead printed out the column tuple. Thanks! I'll take a look at the data.

Comment: Glad I could help. Since this solved it for you, I'll add my last comment as an answer so you can accept it if you like.

Comment: Sure did solve it, there were two columns that had the same exact tuple values. Not sure how or why it affected the loop, but deleting one from the set fixed it. Thanks again!

Comment: It affected the loop because, as the error explicitly stated, you can't sum(`+`) an `int` with a `tuple`, because that is meaningless to python. Happy you got it solved though!

Comment: Right, but according to the loop it should take each instance of the same tuple as a separate occasion? Just trying to learn more.

Comment: The issue is that you're calling, first, `sum(df[col])` for your comparison. This tries to do the sum of all the items at one go, and python doesn't know how to handle something like `0.5+0.1+(0.3,0.1)`, as this is meaningless for the interpreter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This most likely has nothing to do with the number of columns you run it against. It sounds like you have some value in one of the last columns that contains one or more tuples where the rest are numbers. You can run a for loop over the columns to see which don't sum

```
for col in df.columns: 
    try: 
        x=sum(df[col])
    except:
        print(col)
```